# Best way/phrase to say that its too early

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-request

There are certain situations where we need to request customer/client to wait for fair solution or cost. for example -

In a telephonic call client randomly asked to share your thoughts and price to develop XYZ in the existing software. I know 4-5 ways to develop the same thing and not sure which one  is best suited and the cost for it. I replied him something like below -

"Hey John, These (Blah blah..) are the way to do this and it’s too early to decide the best one and its cost right away . i need sometime and will get back to you via email by today or first half tomorrow".

is there any impressive phrase in English which can reduced few sentence ?
 if i am grammatically wrong anywhere in above  sentences please correct. or sugesst some shortest way to pass  the same message.

Answer (score 1):

If by early, you mean that you want more time from him to make a decision, (that's what the situation tells me), I'd recommend a legitimate use of

> Sorry, but as you see choosing the [an adj that describes the quality of the way you choose the best; e.g.: optimum, most productive etc.] way is hard to do instantly/at the moment. **I'll need more time to put my thoughts together and will be able to respond in ...**

Answer (score 0):

revised for grammaticality and common usage (USA):

there are n ways to do this:
—Blah
—Bleh
—Bluh

"But I can't determine quickly which of these will {work best/be the quickest/cost the least/be the optimum solution}. "<-- depending which you think is most important to him
"So I need some time." (<-- note 2 separate words) 
" I will get back to you via email today, or [at the latest] by {noon/midday} tomorrow".